# Screen Lightning Flow, Look Up a Record By Name in a Text Field

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow

Is there a way (without a Lightning Component), to insert a Text Box that Does a Look Up for a record, like in the Product Fields that you get all the options for possible products, or in any Account Field that Shows you the Account so you can search it or create it?

Comment: [Creating Lookup field in Flow](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/creating-lookup-field-in-flow/) might be close to what you're looking!

Comment: A dynamic record choice can do this, but the results are on the next screen, and it's not a great ux. A real lookup field will be a huge improvement, whenever it finally arrives. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_elements_screen_dynchoice.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null